# What kind of layout should I use for this Java GUI assignment?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jlabel

[image]

I've created two panels, one for the JLabel's and textfields, and the other for the text area. However this is our first GUI assignment, and I'm new to all the different layouts. I've already tried group layout to try and align the text field and label but it didn't work out for me. I was just wondering which layout would be best in achieving the desired look?

Comment: What **is** your desired look?

Comment: I'd use [Matisse](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html).

Comment: Understand that usually one single layout won't do, that usually you'll want to nest JPanels, each using its own layout. Also the fun is in the experimenting with the different layouts. So check out the tutorials, play with the layouts to see how they change your GUI, and see if you can come up with an OK solution.

Comment: I "looks" like compunded `GridLayout`s, but I'd use a combination of `GridLayout` and `GridBagLayout` across multiple containers

Answer (score 3):

The basic answer is to use different layouts for different sections, for example, I'd prefer to use a `GridBagLayout` for the details pane and a `GridLayout` to layout the details and the associated text component, but you could use one or more `GridBagLayout`s if you were clever.

The basic idea though, is to isolate functionality and focus on the individual requirements

[image: Layout]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new ProjectPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ProjectPane extends JPanel {

        public ProjectPane() {
            JPanel detailsPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);

            detailsPane.add(new JLabel("Project Name"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            detailsPane.add(new JLabel("Project Number"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            detailsPane.add(new JLabel("Project Location"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            detailsPane.add(new JLabel("Initial Funding"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            detailsPane.add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            detailsPane.add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            detailsPane.add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            detailsPane.add(new JTextField(10), gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

            detailsPane.add(new JButton("Create a project"), gbc);

            setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
            add(detailsPane);
            add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea("No Project")));

        }

    }

}
```

Now the code above focuses on the layout, but I'd be tempted to make the `detailsPane` a separate component, thus allowing me to isolate its functionality to it's own class, but that's me

The component is, obviously, contained within a `JTabbedPane` which is been added to a container using a `BorderLayout`, if that's important

Have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) and [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for some more details